# Необходимо найти элемент в строке

Tags: python

мне нужна ваша помощь. Я начал изучать Питон и у меня есть задание.
Строка со списком ходов в шахматной партии, например 1. d2 - ход белых, e6 - ход черных.
Необходимо на какой ходу у белых была рокировка. Это 7 ход - значение 0 - 0.

```python
chess = '1. d2 e6 2. e4 d5 3. Кc3 c5 4. Кf3 O-O 5. e:d5 e:d5 6. Сe2 Кf6 7. O-O Сe7 8. Сg5 Кc6 9. d:c5 Сe6 10. Кd4 С:c5 11. Кb3 Сe7 12. Сf3 Кe5 13. Лe1 К:f3+ 14. Ф:f3 Лc8 15. h3 h6'
```

Я разбил строку при помощи сплит:

```python
x = chess.split()[1::3]
```

чтобы получить все ходы белых:

```python
['d2', 'e4', 'Кc3', 'Кf3', 'e:d5', 'Сe2', 'O-O', 'Сg5', 'd:c5', 'Кd4', 'Кb3', 'Сf3', 'Лe1', 'Ф:f3', 'h3']
```

Проблема в том, что в строке этот рокировка идет на 7 ходу, а после развибвки, строка "0-0" стоит на 6-ой позиции. Благодарю Вас.

Comment: так номера ходов осчитываются с 1, а индексы в массиве с 0

Comment: Да, это понятно, вот вопрос, как это сделать, потому что в строке указано - 7 ход. Соответственно, непонятно, как правильно сделать, чтобы показать 7ход.  Благодарю Вас.

Comment: так  ход=index+1 - это нужно?

Comment: я поставил минус вопрос за заголовок, который вообще никак не связан с сутью вопроса и вводит в заблуждение

Comment: Если посчитать вручную, то окажется, что 0-0 как раз и стоит на позиции 7, а не 6.

Comment: Зря вы весь код не привели. Реально там просто единичку надо было добавить, чтобы перевести нумерацию с машинного языка в человеческий.

Comment: `[(i, turn) for i, turn in enumerate(chess.split()[1::3], 1)]` рокировка белых на седьмом ходу... что вас смущает?

Comment: @да, вы правы, извиняюсь.

Comment: @MBo   вы знаете, мне кажется, вы правы, потому что мне нужно задачу решить без циклов, и не могу найти решение.

Comment: @Эникейщик Если посчитать вручную, то окажется, что 0-0 как раз и стоит на позиции 7, а не 6. –  Вы знаете, на 7-ой позиции О-О в строке, а в списке на 6ой

Comment: @Jack_oS Благодарю Вас, но у меня указание сделать без цикла.

Comment: chess.split()[1::3].index('0-0')+1

Comment: @Jack_oS   Большое Вам, спасибо, я уже и не знал с этим делать

Comment: Нет, на 7 позиции в строке стоит символ "e" или пробел, смотря с чего вы начинаете счет. А в списке 0-0 стоит на седьмой позиции, а индекс у него 6. Потому что счет позиций начинается с 1, а вот индексация с 0.

Comment: @Эникейщик вы правы, я имел ввиду о-о, идет в строке после 7. Еще раз приношу извинения.